# Getting array data from an file inside \config

Tags: php, mustache, kohana-3.2

Kohana 3.2 with Kostache Mustache.

I'm new on this.

I have this in a view

```
$this->config = Kohana::$config->load('information');
 if(isset($this->config["techinfo"][Request::current()->param('product')]))
 {
 $response['techinfo']['param']=$this->config["techinfo"][Request::current()->param('product')]["param"];
 }
```

In Information.php, I have a lot of data, like name, value, param and other stuff. Don't ask me why. This file has only a simple return array with data information inside.

What this does: the name of the array value is the same the name of the url product. So if it is `/brand/category/product-A`, the information is from product-A, and if it is `/brand/category/product-B`  is his information that comes.

Template file has only  `{{#product}}{{#techinfo}}{{param}}{{/techinfo}}{{/product}}>`
Saying again: Don't ask me why, but it works. I've got this site this way.

My problem:
I need to use the same file to get  information. I can do this, but only if I duplicate de data. And I don't want to do this.

In a newer view, but the  `$this->config = Kohana::$config->load('information');` it's the same.
But how I got de data from there?

Answer (score 0):

To get a variable from your config, use this:

```
    $this->config = Kohana::$config->load('less');
    $path = $this->config->get('path');
```

Make sure you don't have a similar config filed in one of the modules that is overriding your config file.  You may notice the wrong values in that case due to the HMVC.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really got the data  
I did in View

 `public function faqinfo()
    {
  $this->config = Kohana::$config->load('supportinfo');
  $path = $this->config->get('techinfo');
  
  print("<pre>");
 print_r($path);
 die('died');
 }`

but the problem now is that it is bring all the data even doing this in his template.mustache

`{{#faqinfo}}
{{arrayName}}
{{/faqinfo}}`


i tried something like `$path = $this->config->get('techinfo')['arrayName'];`
but, of course it did not work. 

could you help me again?

Comment: can you send us the output of print_r($path) and can you also show me the line where you pass the variable from the controller to the view (something like $this->response->template->arrayName = $path['arrayName'])?

Comment: I pasted the print here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7LSdu/).I didn't find that line. I found only $this->response->body($this->view);. I don't know if it is this way cause im using kostache. Just to review, in the other pages that bring that data has the structure a pasted in my question. Hope it's help!!!

Comment: I think you need to look at the [Kostache pages](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache) to figure out their syntax...I don't use it and it doesn't quite make sense to me.  A simple way of making sure your config is working is to do $this->response->body($this->config['arrayName']) or just print_r($this->config) and make sure the values exist.  It seems you're using config for entries...it actually would make more sense to store that information in a database of some sort instead.

Comment: I know it's not the right way. A database it's the right answer for that. Anyway I'm glad with your help. Tks. I will keep trying waiting for a database guy here where I work. If I get to something I will post here!